# Having google and apple maps in the app

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Apple Maps as default maps in my view.

I would need to integrate Google Maps in my app, and give users to select type of map:
Google Map or Apple Map.

I have different methods, which show radius overlay, pins, and other thing. Is there any ways to have 1 MapView, and just to change type of the map? google or apple.

Whats is the best practice with integration both maps to the app.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to simply use both different maps and switch between them because they do not share the same API, or even a similar API. This means that every single piece of information needs to be handled appropriately for each individual map because annotations and overlay are handled differently on each map. My recommendation would be to use UIViewControllerContainment, create a class, something like VRMapViewController, put the methods this class needs to implement in order to have some data added/removed, and then implement two subclasses: VRAppleMapViewController and VRGoogleMapViewController. In this subclasses you will handle the customization needed for each control in order to present the data inside the map (configuring annotations and overlays, etc). Each class will also handle delegate callbacks from their respective map views.